# Why is the cut on young Spock's lip red and not green if Vulcans have green blood?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-2009, vulcan

In *Star Trek (2009)*, little Spock gets into a fight with three other Vulcans. After the scene he is shown talking with his dad. Spock has a bruise/scab/cut whatever on his lip but it is red. Why isn't it green?

Comment: Because the reboot movies are an abomination unto Roddenberry, hallowed be his name.

Comment: Don't forget, Spock is half Vulcan.. He can sometimes bleed red and sometimes green.. :)

Answer (score 23):

Within the scene, you can see green blood on the lip.

[image: Young Spock - green blood on the split lip] (Click to enlarge)

I have not found an image of the scab you are talking about, but it is possible that the blood changes color as it becomes de-oxygenated, much as with human blood, which goes from a bright red to a brown as it scabs over. Unfortunately, we don't know the exact mechanism of Vulcan blood, because [it doesn't follow Terran examples of copper-based blood](http://articles.eklhad.net/copper).

> The Vulcans on Star Trek have green blood - green because its oxygen ferrying protein (whatever that is) is based on copper, rather than iron. So we are told early on in the Original Series. This is all science fiction, right? Not entirely. There are animals on earth with copper based blood. It isn't bright green however, but a deep blue, or perhaps bluish-green when oxygenated, and dark gray when deoxygenated. I suppose the make-up artists on Star Trek thought vivid green would be more striking.

Just for the sake of completeness, Earth does have one vertebrate with green blood, the appropriately-named [green-blooded skink](https://news.nationalgeographic.com/2015/03/150312-blood-antarctica-octopus-animals-science-colors/). However, its coloration is not due to copper, but due to high levels of [biliverdin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biliverdin), a byproduct of hemoglobin breakdown, in their blood (and other tissues, including their bones).

[image: Green skink blood]
**Red blood vs Green blood**

Comment: There are two principal oxides of copper. I've not delved too deeply into the coloration of them, but I do know that they differ.

Comment: Cherry Popsicles are another possibility, although I don't Know if Vulcan kids partake.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger: No, they don't. There is no logic in providing children such an inefficient sugar delivery system.

Answer (score -2):

Spock isn't fully Vulcan but has a human mother by the name of Amanda Grayson and while his father Sarek is Vulcan.

Yes we are dealing with syfy laws but maybe the blending of species with the two different blood types eg iron based for humans it could affect the visual colour of blood

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se] - and a Happy New Year. Could you provide a quote from anybody affiliated with the production or another official Star Trek source to undermine your theory. Guesswork may be fine to a certain degree, if based on established facts / canon of the fictional universe in question (the answer sometimes just is not known or knowable but it could still be possible to make an *educated* guess). However, just *random* guesswork is likely going to collect downvotes.

Comment: @BMWurm: Why would anyone want to undermine their own theory? Perhaps you are looking for citations that *support* the theory.

Comment: @DaveTweed Yeah of course ... New Years, I hadn't slept that much ...